How can i send a post request before the flask directory is executed
I have a webpage where i want to send a variable 'Email' to my flask script with ajax at an onload function, but the flask script executes before the javascript does, so the flask essentialy receives nothing. I was wondering if there was a way to go around this or maybe a better way to do it.
this is my onload function at account.html:
     function onLoad(){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/account',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'Email', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('AccountInfo'))[2]},
        success: function(response) { 
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = response; 
        }, 
        error: function(error) { 
            console.log(error); 
        } 

      })
    }

and this is my flask directory script:
@app.route('/account', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def account():
  LoggedInEmailAccount = request.form.get('Email')
  print(LoggedInEmailAccount)
  lijstbestelling = []
  lijstdatum = []
  lijstbestelnummer = []
  lijstprijs = []
  if Bestellingen.query.filter_by(email=LoggedInEmailAccount).all() is not None:
    user = Bestellingen.query.filter_by(email=LoggedInEmailAccount).all()
    for i in user:
      i = i.bestelling
      lijstbestelling.append(i)
    for j in user:
      j = j.datum
      lijstdatum.append(j)
    for k in user:
      k = k.bestelnummer
      lijstbestelnummer.append(k)
    for m in user:
      m = m.prijs
      lijstprijs.append(m)
    
  return render_template("account.html", bestellingen=Bestellingen.query.all(), allebestellingen = lijstbestelling, alledatum = lijstdatum, allebestelnummer = lijstbestelnummer, alleprijs = lijstprijs)

LoggedInEmailAccount is the variable that my ajax function is sending, but because the flask directory runs before the onload function it receives nothing.
